# JQuery fadeIn not running in IE10, 9, 8 ,7 or Opera

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This is the current code I'm using to fade in an image which works in FF and Chrome:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".rightcolimage").fadeIn(3000);
    });
```

I can't get it to work in any version of IE and it has problems in Opera. This is the css for .rightcolimage:

```
.rightcolimage{
    display:none;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap your code inside `$(function(){ })` instead of `window load`.

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rightcolimage").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Comment: How this would fix OP's issue?

Comment: This is not the problem. OP is binding to the `window` load event so that all images are visible before code is executed.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. The other problem is I need the image to fadein after all the dom elements have loaded so document.ready wouldn't work in this case. window.load is appropriate but it isn't functioning in IE and I can't figure out why. Is there any conditional code I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of few things.

1. make sure your div has content inside of it, because if its empty you will not see any effects. so add some `width`, `height` and `background color` so it will show you that DOM because if `DOM` does not have content then it will not show anything.
2. make sure that div is exists,

Comment: I already have the image sitting inside a div with fixed width and length so this is not the issue. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @Xochi okay, can you please create fiddle for that so it would be great to see what is wrong.